# Хеш Java Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, хеширование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из указанного `byte[]` получить хеш по **ГОСТ Р 34.11-94.**

К примеру, есть определенный текст

```
String text = "abcd"; //Из этого получаю input 
byte[] input = text.getBytes();
```

дальше мне надо из `byte[]` получит хеш.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через родной механизм `Java`:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); //регистрируем провайдера, можно выполнить где-нибудь статически

byte[] text="abcd".getBytes();
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("GOST3411",BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME); //второй параметр можно опустить
byte[] resultHash = md.digest(text);
```

Напрямую через `BC`:

```
byte[] text="abcd".getBytes();
GOST3411.Digest md = new GOST3411.Digest();
byte[] resultHash = md.digest(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу Темка тоже -
Доступные алгоритмы для хеширования через bouncycastle можно найти  на их сайте в подразделе Digest:
https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html

Примеры для ГОСТа:
GOST3411
GOST3411-2012-256
GOST3411-2012-512

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)